# Angular Plugin System

Tags: angular, plugins

my company bilds machines for special purposes. I’m responsible for a Winows application which connects the machines with the customers software or offers some visualizations etc. Because the software has to offer different features for every customer I realized it as plugin system, so we only need to deploy the necessary plugins for each customer.

One feature, that is requested more and more, is a Web Frontend. Because we offer a WebServer/RestApi Plugin it is not a big thing to build and deploy a SPA solving the needs of the customer. I use Angular to build this Frontends.

The problem I have is the reusability of the Angular applications. The thing I would love to have is something comparable to the Plugin System of the main Application. It would be perfect, if a Plugin would be able to bring its own part of web frontend. A main part hast to detect that modules, generate navigation entries for them and has to lazy load them if called.
But I have no idea if this would be possible and how to start.

So I want to ask the more advanced Angular developers about there estimation if this idea could be realized by Angular and some tips about mechanisms I have to examine closer to reach my goal.

I know this is a unusual use of Web technique, but the conditions are like described. A real cloud solution is not possible, because the customers do not want to connect their machines to the internet, but they want to access the (read only) user interface form every device that is connected to there intranet.
And I want to avoid the need to deploy a huge monolithic SPA to each customer hiding the unused program parts.

Comment: Take a look at micro front ends : https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-implement-micro-frontend-architecture-with-angular-e6828a0a049c

Comment: Thank you for the Link. Looks promising on first view.